# Can I use Punishing Kick with weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I'm building a duelist that has [Punishing Kick](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/punishing-kick-combat) and a rapier as her main weapon. Now do I just add the Punishing Kick to my normal attacks, or do I need to make an unarmed strike in order to use it?

The rules don't appear to state that you need to make an unarmed attack to have it work, but I could be wrong.

The feat does not explicitly say it has to be an unarmed strike, but I strongly suspect that the intention is that it be only usable on unarmed attacks. Alas, other abilities have weird sounding names, considering how you can combine and use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is strongly implied that it has to be an unarmed strike.  Pathfinder isn't designed to be NP-complete, it relies on reasonable interpretation to work.  It's not the letter of the law, but it's the clear intent in my opinion as a Pathfinder GM.

Answer (score 3):

### Punishing Kick

It was clearly intended to work only with unarmed strikes, it looks like possibly as an ability of the Hungry Ghost Monk before they turned it into a bonus feat.

That said, I don't really see any problem with using it as a rider effect on a regular attack.  It makes a lot of sense for me for a swashbuckler to hit someone with a rapier and then push them away with a kick as part of a single action.  Perfectly Errol Flynnish, and i'd allow it in a game I ran with little difficulty.

Comment: One could imagine using Punishing kick in place of one of the attacks in a full attack action aswell.